# How do I run a previously updated React Native project in Xcode 12.3?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am new to coding. I recently had a coder update a React Native appI got it to run on Android with an emulator but there are multiple issues when getting the app to run on IOS. I am assuming the main issue is that I need to clean the react native app for IOS, and I have trouble finding information how to do this...WHat I tried was going to the iOS in the terminal and typing "xcodebuild clean" but errors still pursue....I tried opening up xxx. xcodeproj and I got an error that said "yogakit/yogakit.modulemap' not found". Then I tried opening up xxx.xcworkspace and it got an error saying that I need to update to Swift 5 but the update fails. I ve tried to research this issue everywhere but could not find a solution. What is it that I am doing wrong here? How do you take an updated code from Native React and get it to successfully run in Xcode?